# Pressing enter doesn't work

Tags: automation, autoit

I'm trying to make an automation script that presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> when some popup comes up. It seems to identify the popup window, but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not working. The code is like below:

```
#RequireAdmin
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

$hWnd = WinWaitActive("[TITLE:testpop]")
Sleep(300)
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.
Are you sure the popup remains "focused"?
Or responds to Enter?

```
$hWnd = WinWait("[TITLE:testpop]")
Sleep(300)
WinActivate($hWnd)
Sleep(300)
ControlSend($hWnd,"",0,"{ENTER}")
```

This ^ should do the same but slightly on background.
You can also click a button with ControlClick if you are able to identify the buttons ID with Au3Info.exe

What kind of popup is it?